# flutter web back button not calling dispose (video keeps playing in the background)

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

Im writing a flutter web app using `auto_route` package for navigation. Im having a problem that when the back button is clicked on a page where a video is playing the sound keeps playing in the background. After some tests I discovered the `dispose` function is not being called. I tried using `WillPopScope` but the `onWillPop` function is also never called.